# How do i check <p> element is empty using class?

Tags: javascript

How do i check if the

element is empty or not using class.
for e.g.

```html
n=1
while (n<4) {
 if (checks if p element class(n) is empty){
 //Replaces the p element with variable
}
 else {
 n++}
```

```html
<p id="working" class="machine1"></p>
<p id="working" class="machine2"></p>
<p id="working" class="machine3"></p>
```

Comment: Your "id" values should all be different. An id should be unique within a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/querySelectorAll)** to get all the `<p>` with a specific class.

> **id is always specific for a element.Two elements cannot have same `id`**.Same classes can be used on a elements which have same functionality of some kind.

Check if element is empty by comparing is `innerHTML` to `''`

```js
let paras = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.working'));
paras.forEach((para,i) => {
  if(para.innerHTML === '') para.innerHTML = i;
})
```

```html
<p class="working" id="machine1"></p>
<p class="working" id="machine2"></p>
<p class="working" id="machine3"></p>
```